# how to use filters the word in bash

Tags: regex, bash

This is my output from `cat /etc/resolve.conf`

How can I just show the all nameservers ?

```
 Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.287.53.7
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: You tagged your question as `regex`. So you do know what you need. Have you searched for solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy:

```
grep -i "nameserver" /etc/resolve.conf
```

I added "-i" as you never know somebody starts writing with capitals.